# Need the pinout for this noname FTDI board

Tags: arduino, ftdi

I would really like to know the pinout for this FTDI board.
It has no model number on it and on google picture search I couldn't find it.

It has 2x4 pins on the end of the two sides soldered in.
I figured out which one is the +-5V I just need to know the RX/TX for sure and I don't need anything else to program an atmega 328P which has bootloader on it already, is that correct?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to Arduino?

Comment: no markings on the IC?  cant do a continuity test to see what pins are connected to the board edge?  or other components?

Comment: The pictures are terrible. Try again without washing out all the detail with the flash. Or, just look up the pinout the FTDI chip and follow the traces.

Comment: Based on the package, the chip is most likely FT232R, and the board resembles Sparkfun's FTDI board... if it's meant for connecting to an arduino pro mini that should follow the same pinout.

Answer (score 3):

Get the [FT232R datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) and trace the pinout from the chip. The dimple in the chip is closest to pin 1. I'll do the first one for you, Pin 2 = Receiving Asynchronous Data Input which is the first pin that is unpopulated on the left side when you hold the usb end towards you on the top of the board. If the traces go under the board or you have no interest in investigating the PCB by sight, then put a meter on the pin of interest in ohms mode and touch it to every pin untill you see continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks with the datasheet I figured it out.

Looking at the board on the first picture the pinouts were from left to right:

1 - rx
2 - tx
3 - VCC
4 - GND

Some tutorial mentions that you have to connect the DTR to the reset pin:

http://electronics-diy.com/FT232RL_USB_to_Serial_Adapter_for_PIC_AVR_ATMEGA_ARDUINO_MCUs.php

Is that so? Because some don't, they just say rx,tx is enough. I still can't program the chip with the error:

```
 avrdude -p m328p -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -c avrisp -b 9600 -n -v -v -v

avrdude: Version 5.11.1, compiled on Oct 18 2011 at 21:17:35
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : avrisp
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 9600
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I tried different baud rates, no matter what it's not responding. Linux recognizes the FTDI as:

```
Sat Feb 13 22:52:14 2016] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:14 2016] ftdi_sio 1-2.1:1.0: device disconnected
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:19 2016] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 73 using uhci_hcd
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: SerialNumber: A6004mhS
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] ftdi_sio 1-2.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: Detected FT232RL
[Sat Feb 13 22:52:20 2016] usb 1-2.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[Sat Feb 13 22:56:25 2016] usb 1-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 73
[Sat Feb 13 22:56:25 2016] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[Sat Feb 13 22:56:25 2016] ftdi_sio 1-2.1:1.0: device disconnected
```

Well my questions now are:

1, When I use the Arduino IDE to program a barebone 328P with this FTDI what should be the **BOARD** and what should be the **PROGRAMMER**?

Right now I have it on Arduino Nano/Atmega328 + AVRISP mkII

Although I tried almost all... I think something else is wrong.

2, Should I be able to get any result with doing the previous:

```
 avrdude -p m328p -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -c avrisp -b 9600 -n -v -v -v
```

command WITHOUT connecting the barebone chip? I think not, since this doesn't act like a fully fledged MCU just like a serial converter.

Thanks